# Azure AD OAuth Refreshing Tokens

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm making an application that among it's task will use the REST API in KeyVault. I already have functions written that will query the KeyVault for the secret without an issue.
I also have functions written to request an OAuth token from AAD, following the documentation on this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code

What I'm not sure about is; Since the application is going to be installed on hundreds of computers when a token expires and the function to refresh the token is called chances are that more than one PC is going to make the POST. What is the best practice for a scenario like this? Should i just configure an exponential back off after a refresh token function is called?

The app installed on the machines will not have the ability to talk to each other.

The only way I can think to do this is to use a logic app as the broker but that would defeat the purpose of the KeyVault.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is your concern here. Can you please edit your question and elaborate the following `when a token expires and the function to refresh the token is called chances are that more than one PC is going to make the POST`? Thanks.

Comment: @GauravMantri This is a client side application running on multiple PCs, since each instance running will request use the same AAD token it means that when it expires more than one PC could request a refresh

Comment: `since each instance running will request use the same AAD token` - I think this is where your confusion comes in. Essentially each user will get their own AAD token as mentioned by Fei Xue in the answer.

Comment: I'm not using user based authentication, I'm using an AppID and Secret to generate the AAD token since the application is transparent to the user and they don't interact with it. So every instance of the running app ends up receiving the same token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some testing and verifying with MS it looks like the documentation on the link is outdated. When a token is generated it has a lifetime of 8 hours (this is configurable) so every time I make a request to /token a new token is handed out, since the time window is small I don't need to worry about token refreshes since PCs won't be on for over 8 hours.

The other part of this is that i built a function to test the validity of the existing token, before i query any azure service i test the token validity, if it fails a new token is requested. Since the token lifetime windows are short and each machine gets it's own token (i thought all machines were getting the same token, code error on my part) this is a non-issue anymore

Answer (score 0):

The document you provided is using the **code grant flow** to acquire the access token. This flow requires users to login to acquire the token. And did you mean all the PC you installed will use the same account to acquire the token?

If yes, you can design you own [token cache](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/blob/3a74da1a8d6193ae91cc975a5a8cd4719373534e/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/TokenCache.cs). For example, you can using an SQL server to store the cache. Then the app will search the token/refresh token in the token cache before it sends the token request. And if the token is expired, you can refresh it. In this scenario, all PC will share the same access token since they are sign-in with same account.

If not, you need to refresh for the every PC when the access token is expired. Because the access token is different from each user.

Comment: Wouldn't storing a token for AAD within a SQL instance defeat the purpose of KeyVault? If I need to query an Azure SQL instance for an AAD token then I may as well store the secret inside SQL and query SQL.

I also forgot to mention I'm not using user credentials, i'm using an AppID generated by AAD specifically for this app

Comment: The SQL Server is just one of solution for demonstrating. You can implement the token cache as you want.  And what's the exact command you were using? Or can you share the request you were acquiring the access token?

Comment: Ii'm using the same request as the example on the link i posted, the section named "Use the authorization code to request an access token". The main difference when i'm using OAuth on Azure vs other services is that with every token request that i send each application instance gets its own unique token so refreshing it is a 1-1 task. With Azure it seems to be a many-to-1 hence my question here.